Databricks SQL query very slow when comparing datetime
In Databricks SQL, I have a query that takes forever to execute, which in our old system wouldn't take more then 2 hours (4 minutes even for this piece of the query). I have traced the problem to the following piece where it keeps getting stuck on the datetime compare. If I comment out the part with the datetime, it just takes under 2 minutes to execute.
Extra info:
size of table_x: 28.000
size of table_y: 23.500.000
size of table_z: 19
example of datetime value: 2020-10-19T14:40:00.000
The old system uses OUTER APPLY instead of LEFT JOIN LATERAL, but this shouldn't be a problem?
query:
SELECT
    count(1)
FROM table_x
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT
        SUM(col_x)
    FROM table_y
    INNER JOIN table_z
        ON table_y.z_id = table_z.`id`
    WHERE table_y.col_y = table_x.col_y
    AND table_y.`DATE` >= table_x.DAYDATEFROM
    AND table_y.`DATE` < table_x.DAYDATEUNTIL
) xyz_data

I have tried commenting out the datetime, which works perfectly. And afterwards filtering with a where on examples of values from table_y.DATE, which also doesn't cause any problems or duplicates as far as I tried this with some examples.
Are there any more strategies I can try or is there a known issue that I didn't find?
Edit: casting the columns to TIMESTAMP doesn't seem to help either
Edit 2: I did not find any NULL values, or values in the wrong format.

You can partition a field, see https://docs.databricks.com/en/tables/partitions.html
Here it is being said that they are being some kind of index: Indexes for Databricks (Spark SQL) tables
So if you can partition your table by dates, then filters based on those dates will be quicker.
You will need to make sure that your date field is of date type indeed as well.

Databricks doesn't recommend this for tables under 1tb, and my largest table in this query is just over 1GB. This also doesn't explain why my old system (using SSMS) does this query in under 4 minutes while Databricks can't do it in multiple hours.

@Troebel58 what is the type of your Date field?

Date, DAYDATEFROM and DAYDATEUNTIL are all Timestamp.
